# One finger gesture recognizer with normal uibuttons

Tags: xcode4, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using some parts of code of this one finger gesture recogniser:

```
http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2012/02/13/an-one-finger-rotation-gesture-recognizer/
```

and I add three unbuttons with touch in mode. When I implemented this in xcode and run my app on simulator the buttons worked fine only when I swipe on them. They don't recognise one touch click on them. What should I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to implement one delegation method as below

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
    return YES;
}
```

For more explanation just use [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture) example.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: It doesn't help. I implemented it to my controller class but it still works the same.

Comment: have you seen the examples viewDidLoad: method ? the first for loop and the tap recognizer with the requireGestureRecognizerToFail: statements ?